# yum errors with 404

Tags: rhel, yum, dnf

I am running RHEL 7.6 on virtualbox and have been trying to install `dnf` using `yum`. `yum install dnf` errors with the following:
[image: yum errors]

Not only this, other commands like `yum check-update`, `yum list` etc also fail with similar errors. I have had a look at the following but didnt help at all:

1. https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1421903
2. https://access.redhat.com/articles/5140651

In case it helps, this is my `/etc/yum.conf`:
[image: yum.conf contents]

Can someone point out what is going wrong? How do I fix this?

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're wanting to install dnf?

Comment: Apologies if this sounds insensitive, but what part of the error message isn't clear? It states that a specific repository has failed, and then provides several approaches to fix it. It's not specific to a package or even a specific `yum` operation.

Comment: Please do not post images of text.

Comment: @cutrightjm to install an rpm file, seemed a lot of effort auto-installing dependencies with yum

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak This is a VM as I mentioned, haven't figured out how to copy and paste between host and local machines

Comment: @Haxiel You don't know how much I have tried, I did follow all the approaches to "fix" the problem, nothing seemed to work. I did  go through article 1320623 as well but somehow missed the November 2020 comment pointed out by the accepted answer.

Comment: `dnf` is the new yum https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNF_(software) .... and you can install rpm packages with dnf , just like you used to do with yum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message suggests to look at: https://access.redhat.com/articles/1320623

It has a note from November 2020, describing an upcoming change that requires all users of extended update streams (EUS, E4S, TUS, AUS) to use the `subscription-manager release` command to persistently set the supported minor release level they wish to use. It further refers to https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4780531 for more detailed instructions on setting the release.

Since the repository URL you're using includes `/e4s/`, you seem to be using an extended update stream and the note should be applicable to your system.

If you haven't set the release level, or have it set incorrectly, the error message is apparently normal and expected.

The example in the note suggests the supported release values are something like `7.6`. The repository URL in the error message suggests your release might be currently set to `7.6-4.el7` which may not be a valid value.

Run `subscription-manager release --list` to see the list of supported releases, and `subscription-manager release --set=<release>` to set one of the supported values.

After that, you should clear the `yum` cache as indicated in article 1320623 after the note.

Comment: I did open that article as well but somehow I missed the November 2020 comment. Perhaps didnt scroll all the way down. That worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: At this point there’s hardly a good reason for sticking with an EUS.  RHEL7 is in maintenance mode so no more point releases are coming out.  7.6 eus support ended in May 2021, and the final rhel 7 eus is 7.7 and it ended in August 2021.